# Which of these two is the correct translation for "Silly me"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, grammatical-case

`Me` is nominative here. So what it should be?

> Bin ich dumm!

or

> Dumm ich!

Comment: Is really "me" nominative? I would think that "I" is nominative, not "me".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Lennart: Just because a sentence starts with a verb doesn't mean it should be a question. "Spiel nicht mit deinem Essen!" "Wollte er es, hätte er es gemacht."

Ich würde "silly me" mit "Ich Schussel" oder "Ach, natürlich..." ("... muss ich es so machen!") übersetzen.

Comment: Comments to Lennart should be postet below his answers. If he deletes the answer, it will not be overseen. If the sorting of answers differs, your comment will not be in front of the text it comments.

Comment: What does the "@Lennart" part refer to? In any case, this answer is too unspecific. I can think of plenty of opportunities where I could imagine saying "Silly me.", but where "Ich Schussel." would not seem fitting. At least in my experience, *Schussel* has quite a specific meaning compared to "silly me".

Answer (score 10):

The phrase "silly me" is colloquial English. The German equivalent, "Bin ich dumm!", is colloquial, too ([dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/Silly+me.html)).

A more fitting translation would be "Ich Idiot" (or "Ich Schussel", like @Robert suggested), which would be a title you assign to yourself to indicate that you are indeed silly.

Comment: I agree, but can't you say "Bin ich dumm!" with exclamation mark and it would be proper grammar?

Comment: @MartinHansen No.  From Lennart's answer: "...since sentences beginning with a verb should generally be questions."

Comment: I have read it, but I'm not sure if it's incorrect, because it could be used as an interjection. Edit: Or as an "Ausruf" (don't know the english word), like "Ach!" or "Wie schön!"

Comment: @MartinHansen You may be right there. What you mean would indeed be an [Interjektion](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjektion). They are mostly used in spoken language on a personal level. In written language, "Interjektionen" are used as stylistic devices for imitating orality, thus being a mean of colloquial communication. Feel free to correct me, but that is what I learned in school.

Comment: @Martin is absolutely right, exclamations using question word order are very much possible and quite common: _Bin ich blöd!_ _Was bist du für ein Schussel!_